# Cannot cast the structure pointer to char pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to cast the structure pointer with `char*` as an input to a function but unable to print the contents of the structure. This is my header that has to be added to my message.

```
struct ethernet_header
{
    int hlp;
    char info_lenght[20];
    int data_length;

};
```

In my main function I am doing this

```
ethernet_header *eth = new ethernet_header;
    eth->hlp = 4;
    eth->data_length = 10;
m->msgAddHdr((char *)eth,sizeof(ethernet_header));
```

I am trying to print the structure contents in the following manner.

```
cout<<(char *)eth<<endl;
```

even I tried printing

```
cout<<(char *)eth->hlp<<endl;
```

it's throwing an error.

The function `msgAddHdr` will concatwnate the structure to the message. When I tried to print the message with the header concatenated it's showing blank and I can't even print the structure by casting it to `char*`.

When I tried with the structure like this:

```
struct test1
{

    char k = 'r';
};
```

it has worked perfectly. Why is it not working for my original structure?

Comment: `sizeof(test1)` ? You probably mean `sizeof(ethernet_header)`...

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "print the contents of the structure"?  Can you show us in code what you are doing to "print the contents"?

Comment: You just cannot magically print structs by casting them to `char*`. C++ doesn't work this way. If you want to see a struct you need to print it field by field.

Comment: I tried printing field by field but its throwing errors

Comment: We can't help you with errors you won't post in code you won't post.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description (with char), you're trying to print it as a string `printf("%s")`.

If `eth->hlp` will have a value of `0x12000000` (301989888) on x86 machine it will be stored in memory as 0x00000012. And strings in C/C++ are null terminated.

```
while(*ptr != '\0'){
    putc(*ptr);
    ++ptr;
}
```

And since your first byte is `\0` it terminates before the first character.

I would use loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    printf("%02x", *ptr);
    ++ptr;
}
```

To print `char*` as hexadecimal array.

Or if you want to print printable characters (let's assume ASCII and characters between 0x20 and 0x7F) and replace non printable ones with dot `.` you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    if(*ptr < 0x20 || *ptr > 0x7e){
        putc('.');
    } else {
        putc(*ptr);
    }
    ++ptr;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you can use `cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << *ptr`.